# Problem in setting up Djaty nodejs. Nothing sent to Dashboard

Tags: djaty

My current config

```js
djaty.init({
  tags: ['test'],
  apiKey: 'xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  apiSecret: 'xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  release: '0.1.1',
  trackingOptions: {
  captureUnhandledRejections: true,
    allowedWrappers: {
      http: true,
      console: true,
      stdLogs: true,
      customLoggers: [{
        name: 'winston',
        instance: winston,
      }],
    },
  },
});
```

When a bug occur I don't find the log entry `Uncaught exception reported` as mentioned at docs.

Comment: Please try to set `showDjatyLogs: true` to be able to see what happens under the hood and share the logs here

Comment: I have the same problem